# Global sections appearing in Dolbeault complex with values in vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds

Given a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ on a compact complex Kähler manifold $X$ (I am happy to assume $X$ projective), we can compute the sheaf cohomology $H^\ast(E)$ of $E$ using the Dolbeault complex with values in $E$ (see e.g. Huybrechts' book Complex Geometry, Section 2.6).

The Dolbeault complex consists of the (smooth) global sections $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{A}^{0,q}_X \otimes E)$ of the (smooth) bundle $\mathcal{A}^{0,q}_X \otimes E$. Is it known whether the (infinite-dimensional) vector space $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{A}^{0,q}_X \otimes E)$ is generated by tensor products $\omega \otimes v$ with $\omega$ respectively $v$ smooth sections of $\mathcal{A}^{0,q}_X$ respectively $E$? I believe this does not need to hold.

Note that the description of the question [Global Definition of the Dolbeault Complex of a Vector Bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103705/global-definition-of-the-dolbeault-complex-of-a-vector-bundle) seems to assume this is true, whereas the comment underneath says that the operator $\bar{\partial}_E$ only locally agrees with $\bar{\partial} \otimes id$ (which I interpret as a negative answer to my question).

Comment: If the underlying topological space of $X$ is compact, $\Gamma(E)$ is generated as a $C^\infty(X)$-module by finitely many global sections (use a partition of unity to reduce to charts where $E$ is trivialized). Their tensor products with forms $\omega$ then generate the $E$-valued forms. In general, $\Gamma(X;E\otimes F)\cong \Gamma(X;E)\otimes_{C^\infty(X)}^\pi \Gamma(X;F)$ is the *projective* tensor product, a certain completion of the algebraic tensor product. If $E$ or $F$ is a retract of a finite-dimensional free bundle, this completion is not necessary.